# character encoding UTF-8 problem from calling another .Rmd - R

Tags: r, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I have two files: `a.Rmd` and `b.Rmd`, where `b.Rmd` needs to use the `X` dataframe calculated in `a.Rmd` to do some calculations. The input of `a.Rmd` is a `.csv` file saved in `df`, where the encoding is `UTF-8` to handle latin special characters `(ñ, ó)`

```
df <- read.csv("DF.csv", sep = ";", encoding="UTF-8", na.strings="",stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

When I run `a.Rmd` from itself, it does some calculations and gives `X` dataframe as output. Until here everything is perfect:

[image]

However, when I run `a.Rmd` from `b.Rmd` with:

```
rmarkdown::render("a.Rmd")
```

It gives me the same table, but with characters problems like this:

[image]

Why? How can I solve this? In addition, feel free to add/edit some tags, as I don't know well where exactly falls this issue.

Comment: Maybe you can try to set the encoding with the `encoding` parameter in the `render` function.

Answer (score 1):

This solved the issue (thanks to ricoderks)

```
rmarkdown::render("a.Rmd", encoding="UTF-8")
```